# How do i run a python project nonstop ( even when i close the computer )

Tags: python

I have a discord.py bot using the `datetime` and `random` libraries ( and `discord.py` of course ). My question  is how can i run it even when my computer is off. I think the answer is a rented server but i think there are cheeper options

Comment: Not really. Code needs to run __somewhere__ & that somewhere has to be powered on to be running your code. If that's not your computer it has to be some other computer.

Comment: You can try using cloud services like AWS (Amazon Web Services). If it's a small application you might even be able to host your application for free.

Comment: Have you thought about a Raspberry Pi?  We have eight running various server tasks (network, web, database, etc.) and very happy with them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to run it on a machine you don't turn off. Or deploy it to a server. You can get cheap servers through Linode, Digital Ocean and others.

Answer (score 0):

[Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/)
 has a 1 year trial which will do for me